# How to figure out where is my python installed using OS or Sys

Tags: python, operating-system

Is there a way to find out where is my python installed using OS?

Well i know that if we open a shell and run this:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

it will work
but can we do this in idle too ?

when its saved on desktop for example ?

actually I'm looking for this output for example:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
```

Comment: `os.getcwd` returns your current working directory, not the location of either your script or the Python executable.

Comment: `sys.executable` returns the path of Python itself; `sys.argv[0]` is the location of the script (though it may be a path relative to you current working directory) when applicable.

Comment: what exactly are you after? Where your python script is stored? or your working directory when you try to run the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.prefix
```